# modify /change array of object keys by object keys name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, filter

I would like to know how to modify the array of objects key with object key in javascript.

I have array object `arrobj` and object `obj`, i want to change the arrayobject keys with object keys in javascript
i.e change arrayobject keys `name, amt` with object keys `topic and price`

```
let obj={
   status: 1, data:{
   config:{
   topic: "xx", price: "100"}
   }
  }

let arrobj ={
  status:1,
  data: [
    {
      id:1,
      name: "abc",
      amt: "50",
      city: "TH"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name: "zen",
      amt: "100",
      city: "IN"
    },
  ]
}

var result = arrobj.data.map(e=>{
   var tt = obj.data.config
  return Object.keys(tt).forEach(i=>{
    return {
      i:e.name
     }
   })
})


Expected Output

 [
    {
      id:1,
      topic: "abc",
      price: "50",
      city: "TH"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      topic: "zen",
      price: "100",
      city: "IN"
    },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this, we add the new keys to the array in the first map, then remove the old keys in the second

```js
let arrobj = {
  status: 1,
  data: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "abc",
      amt: "50",
      city: "TH"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "zen",
      amt: "100",
      city: "IN"
    },
  ]
}

arrobj.data = arrobj.data.map(e => ({ ...e, topic: e.name, price: e.amt }))
  .map(e => { delete e.amt; delete e.name; return e })

console.log(arrobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj={
   status: 1, data:{
   config:{
   topic: "xx", price: "100"}
   }
  }

let arrobj ={
  status:1,
  data: [
    {
      id:1,
      name: "abc",
      amt: "50",
      city: "TH"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name: "zen",
      amt: "100",
      city: "IN"
    },
  ]
}

var result = arrobj.data = arrobj.data.map(paylaod => {
  let {amt, name, ...rest} = paylaod
  return { 
          ...rest, 
          topic: paylaod.name, 
          price: paylaod.amt 
         }
 
 })
 
 arrobj.data = result;


console.log(arrobj);
```